# python binding saleae logic 2

Tags: python, saleae-logic

Is there a python binding for the saleae logic software?
I know for the deprecated [version 1.2.x](https://support.saleae.com/logic-software/legacy-software/older-software-releases) is a [python binding](https://python-saleae.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) present.

I'm looking for an equivalent for the version 2. I know that the software has already filters, which can be written in python.

#### Used case

To automate a timing analysis I want to run a simple python script. This initiates a saleae recording, afterwards starts the test an when the test is done, the saleae recording should stop. So for my setup, it would be nice to control [saleae logic 2](https://www.saleae.com/downloads/) with an external program. A python binding would we awesome, but if there is some kind of restapi or like additional command line parameters to use it with pipes, it would be also fine.

**So is there a way to remote control Saleae 2 Software?**

Comment: as a matter of fact, I can't see why this is worth to down vote. Maybe someone can enlighten me, why it's a bad question? would appreciate to learn ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://ideas.saleae.com/b/feature-requests/application-api/

> Please note that the Socket API automation utility requires the older
> Logic 1.x software. The latest Logic 2.x software currently does not
> support this utility, though we do plan to add support for it in the
> future. Feel free to [vote](https://ideas.saleae.com/b/feature-requests/application-api/) on the idea here!